# Developing a Secure API for own mobile client

Tags: api, rest, oauth, forms-authentication

I'm developing API - No problems here

The API will be used by my mobile client to communicate with the Webservice.

My problem is I don't know what authentication system so that people can login in the native app and the API knows which user is sending requests.

I can make it OAuth based, but my app is not third party and i want user to goto a webpage etc and i want them to login inside the app and be able to send requests as authenicated user.

What is 2-legged and 3-legged authenication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your API is available over SSL you can simply go for [HTTP Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

But the benefit of OAuth in your scenario is that it works reasonably securely even without a secure transport layer such as SSL, the specification is such that it prevents malicious "replays" of a request, that having been said, without SSL, individual requests can be eavesdropped upon.

You could implement [xAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth), which is basically OAuth but with much easier user authentication. Each API request will still have to be signed, but you can get an access token by sending username and password. This seems like a promising alternative for you.

2-legged authentication is basically for application to application authorization. Basically two applications exchanging API services without a specific end user being involved. 2 legged authorization bypasses the authorization step, and basically immediately provisions an access token.

3-legged involves a user authorizing a third party application (a consumer) to access its resources with a service provider. This scheme involves a temporary token (request token) that the end user must verify, thereby provisioning an access token.

---

Comment: xuath is all the way  itself and isn't it a name twitter has coined. What's the real world terminology?

Comment: There is XAuth (xauth.org) an initiative which has nothing to do with OAuth. And there is xAuth which is a Twitter invention for the OAuth authorization dance. Confusing :)